# CarouselView only displays bound items if visible at Load

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms app and in one page I want to use a CarouselView to display a list of images.

On the said page the user is first presented with Overall details, so the CarouselView is invisible at this point (parent Frame has binding prop IsVisible), and the user can select between 2 options (interior and exterior) to see the images, at this point the CarouselView is now visible to the user and the list that populates the ItemsSource has only the images regarding the selected option.

I have the xaml and code working fine, but the problem is that it only works if the  CarouselView is visible at page load, if the CarouselView is hidden the binding happens but once it becomes visible nothing is displayed. I tried many permutations of visibility and the initial data that is bound to the CarouselView and neither work if the Carousel is hidden.

I am not certain that this behaviour is not linked with the visibility part or a fluke, but just for testing if I make the CarouselView visible by default with the Overall details hidden (opposite functionality than I want) the CarouselView works fine.

One option I considered was to use 2 separate CarouselView's and display/hide each one depending on user option. The problem with that is that I will have more options on the next version and so I would need to add multiple objects to control this.

I created a simple app outside my main code to replicate this behaviour, although I got slight differences on how it gets presented, the behaviour of not loading the data if the CarouselView is hidden continues.

XAML for my page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="carouseltest.Views.ItemsPage" Title="{Binding Title}" x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Frame>
            <StackLayout>
                <Button Text="Overall" Clicked="DisplayChanges_OnClick" CommandParameter="-1"/>
                <Button Text="Interior Pictures" Clicked="DisplayChanges_OnClick" CommandParameter="0"/>
                <Button Text="Exterior Pictures" Clicked="DisplayChanges_OnClick" CommandParameter="1"/>
             </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame IsVisible="{Binding OverallVisible}">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding OverallDetails}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame IsVisible="{Binding PicturesVisible}">
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesSelectedOption}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

.CS file

```
public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage {
    ItemViewModel viewModel;

    public ItemsPage() {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = viewModel = new ItemViewModel {
            OverallDetails = "House For sale 01",
            Images = new List<DisplayImages> {
                new DisplayImages{  ImagePath = "interior_01", Option=0},
                new DisplayImages{  ImagePath = "interior_02", Option=0},
                new DisplayImages{  ImagePath = "interior_03", Option=0},
                new DisplayImages{  ImagePath = "interior_04", Option=0},
                new DisplayImages{  ImagePath = "exterior_01", Option=1},
                new DisplayImages{  ImagePath = "exterior_02", Option=1},
                new DisplayImages{  ImagePath = "exterior_03", Option=1},
                new DisplayImages{  ImagePath = "exterior_04", Option=1}
            }
        };
    }

    void DisplayChanges_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        int selectedValue = -1;
        Button button = sender as Button;
        int.TryParse(button?.CommandParameter?.ToString(), out selectedValue);
        viewModel.overallVisible = selectedValue < 0;
        viewModel.SelectedOption = selectedValue;
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing() {
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
}

public class ItemViewModel : BaseViewModel {

    private int selectedOption = 0;
    public int SelectedOption {
        get { return selectedOption; }
        set {
            selectedOption = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OverallVisible");
            OnPropertyChanged("PicturesVisible");
            OnPropertyChanged("ImagesSelectedOption");
        }
    }
    public bool overallVisible = true;
    public bool OverallVisible {
        get {
            return overallVisible;
        }
    }

    public bool PicturesVisible {
        get {
            return !overallVisible;
        }
    }

    public string OverallDetails { get; set; }

    public List<DisplayImages> Images { get; set; }

    private Dictionary<int, List<DisplayImages>> imagesSelectedOption = new Dictionary<int, List<DisplayImages>>();
    public List<DisplayImages> ImagesSelectedOption {
        get {
            var selOpt = selectedOption;

            if (!imagesSelectedOption.Keys.Contains(selOpt)) {
                List<DisplayImages> displayImages = new List<DisplayImages>();
                displayImages.AddRange(Images.Where(c => c.Option == selOpt).ToList());
                imagesSelectedOption.Add(selOpt, displayImages);
            }

            return imagesSelectedOption[selOpt];
        }
    }
}

public class DisplayImages {
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public int Option { get; set; }
}
```

Other things that I tried:
Changing the CarouselView for a CollectionView with same result.

Thank you so much in advance!

Edit: Adding view showing working and not working examples:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMY0t.jpg

**Edit 2**

After suggestion from @JuniorJiang-MSFT I changed the sample code using his recommendation to rebind the collection and my sample is now working. So to help any others that might benefit from this, I am adding the new code here:

XAML changes - removed the biding to ItemsSource, added Name to Carousel so I can rebind on code:

```
<ContentPage ...>
        <Frame IsVisible="{Binding PicturesVisible}">
            <CarouselView x:Name="carousel">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
        </Frame>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

.CS changes - Added a class level property to rebind the carousel the first time it becomes visible, changed the button code to rebind the coursel:

```
private bool carouselBound = false;
...
void DisplayChanges_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int selectedValue = -1;
    Button button = sender as Button;
    int.TryParse(button?.CommandParameter?.ToString(), out selectedValue);

    viewModel.SelectedOption = selectedValue;
    if (selectedValue >= 0) {
        if (!carouselBound) {
            carouselBound = true;
            carousel.SetBinding(CarouselView.ItemsSourceProperty, "ImagesSelectedOption");
        }
        if (carousel.ItemsSource.OfType<object>().Count() > 0)
            carousel.ScrollTo(0, animate: false);

    }
}
```

Comment: It's a strange phenomenon. Do you have a image to show it ?

Comment: I do, unfortunately its on my Mac and I dont have it with me right now, but will upload one as soon as possible.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Just added a video showing both working and not working scenarios. Really appreciate any help

Comment: Okey , thanks for sharing . I will check it.

Comment: Maybe CollectionView from invisible to visible , need to rebinding itemsource to reload data .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT That was a great thought. I just changed the sample above to re-bind the carousel at the first time it becomes visible and that seems to do it, althought not entirely sure why that would be the case.If you would like to suggest that in a Answer I am happy to accept it, otherwise I will post it just so others can benefit also.

Comment: Okey, thanks for replying and glad it works.I have written in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have the xaml and code working fine, but the problem is that it only works if the CarouselView is visible at page load, if the CarouselView is hidden the binding happens but once it becomes visible nothing is displayed.

From this phenomenon, Control from hidden to visible , data model will not be reloaded again.

Then **solution** should reload data by rebinding itemsource.

Comment: Thanks again @JuniorJiang-MSFT - I updated the question to show my new code using your solution, just in case someone else also needs this.

Comment: @ClaitonLovato Okey，that's great !

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly the same issue:

When toggling visibility of several items in a layout (same with Grid), if one of the item is a CollectionView, a Exception was raised preventing it from displaying.

I forget to open a bug for this one, but it is one...

So far, and till the CollectionView is production ready, you can use https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms#carousel-layout.

Comment: Hi @Roubachof, with the help from Junior, I managed to workaround the issue by rebinding the Carousel. hope this also helps you.